# Batch file to bring back value from csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a csv file that contains:

```
Location, Type, Printer
1, shelf, PrinterA
2, shelf, PrinterB
1, hook, PrinterA
```

I want to pass a batch file a location and a type and it returns the printer into a string.
So I can say - if a `csv` file exists for `Location 1` and `Shelf Type`, set the default printer to `printer`.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or risk a look into Jon Skeet's [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). You are always welcome to ask, but please keep the above in mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

A way !

**use :** *test.bat 1 shelf*

```
@echo off

for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims=," %%a in ('find "%1, %2" "printer.csv"') do (
   set "$printer=%%a"
   goto:next)

echo no data found !!
exit/b

:next
echo Printer is [%$printer:~1%]
```

Comment: Hi SachaDee.  Thanks for the reply.  Can't seem to get this to work, confused by the "USE: test.bat 1 shelf" statement at the top.

Comment: Hi ! In your question you :  **"want to pass a batch file a location and a type"** to get the printer. So that's the parameters that you have to pass to your bat to get the printer. If you have this value inside a bat just replace `%1` and `%2` with other variables.